# Azure Data Factory - Error setting up JSON data source from datalake

Tags: azure-data-factory

When using the Copy-data wizard from de Azure Data Factory, I get the following error:

**"Error when processing request: The property 'Path' in the payload cannot be null or empty. activityId: 7dd0bab2-bb67-4ba8-9075-ca6809e537fd"**

Here's a screenshot of that:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSbZX.png)

This happens when I use the JSON filetype. It occurs with simple and complex JSON files. One of the JSON files I used is the following:

{

```
  "time": "2015-04-29T07:12:20.9100000Z",
  "callingimsi": "466920403025604",
  "callingnum1": "678948008",
  "callingnum2": "567834760",
  "switch1": "China",
  "switch2": "Germany"
```

}

Am I doing something wrong or did I forget something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tried out and it tests well on my side, here is a screenshot.
[my capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vURo.jpg)
Could I know one quick question:
Any chances that you tried with a file name without space (such as test.json rather than test 2.json) or have another try after cleaning the browser caches?

I will check more if the issue still persists.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum; it is a formal Q/A site. Any questions you have should be posted as a comment for the asker to respond. An answer should provide the final solution without asking OP for more details.

Comment: Thank you, apparently I wasn't allowed to store the file in the root of the datalake. By adding a folder and placing the json in there, it worked. Many thanks!